# how fix error? ' ....rubocop- ... revealed dependencies not in the API ..."

Tags: ruby, bundler, ruby-on-rails-6

how do I fix this error?

```sh
+bundle install --jobs 3 --full-index --retry 3 --deployment
Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.17.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.17.3). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Fetching https://github.com/QueueClassic/queue_classic.git
Fetching https://github.com/matthewd/websocket-client-simple.git
Fetching rake 13.0.0
Installing rake 13.0.0
Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
Fetching minitest 5.12.2
Installing minitest 5.12.2
Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6
Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
Fetching zeitwerk 2.2.0
Fetching builder 3.2.3
Installing zeitwerk 2.2.0
Installing builder 3.2.3
Fetching erubi 1.9.0
Fetching mini_portile2 2.4.0
Installing erubi 1.9.0
Fetching crass 1.0.4
Installing mini_portile2 2.4.0
Fetching rack 2.0.7
Installing crass 1.0.4
Fetching nio4r 2.5.2
Installing rack 2.0.7
Installing nio4r 2.5.2 with native extensions
Fetching websocket-extensions 0.1.4
Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.4
Fetching mimemagic 0.3.3
Installing mimemagic 0.3.3
Fetching mini_mime 1.0.2
Installing mini_mime 1.0.2
Fetching public_suffix 4.0.1
Installing public_suffix 4.0.1
Fetching amq-protocol 2.3.0
Installing amq-protocol 2.3.0
Fetching ansi 1.5.0
Installing ansi 1.5.0
Fetching ast 2.4.0
Installing ast 2.4.0
Fetching aws-eventstream 1.0.3
Installing aws-eventstream 1.0.3
Fetching aws-partitions 1.221.0
Installing aws-partitions 1.221.0
Fetching jmespath 1.4.0
Installing jmespath 1.4.0
Fetching multipart-post 2.1.1
Installing multipart-post 2.1.1
Fetching beaneater 1.0.0
Installing beaneater 1.0.0
Fetching dante 0.2.0
Installing dante 0.2.0
Fetching bcrypt 3.1.13
Installing bcrypt 3.1.13 with native extensions
Fetching benchmark-ips 2.7.2
Installing benchmark-ips 2.7.2
Fetching blade-qunit_adapter 2.0.1
Installing blade-qunit_adapter 2.0.1
Fetching coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Fetching execjs 2.7.0
Installing execjs 2.7.0
Fetching curses 1.0.2
Installing curses 1.0.2 with native extensions
Fetching eventmachine 1.2.7
Installing eventmachine 1.2.7 with native extensions
Fetching cookiejar 0.3.3
Installing cookiejar 0.3.3
Fetching http_parser.rb 0.6.0
Installing http_parser.rb 0.6.0 with native extensions
Fetching multi_json 1.13.1
Installing multi_json 1.13.1
Fetching daemons 1.3.1
Installing daemons 1.3.1
Fetching thor 0.20.3
Installing thor 0.20.3
Fetching useragent 0.16.10
Installing useragent 0.16.10
Fetching childprocess 3.0.0
Installing childprocess 3.0.0
Fetching rubyzip 2.0.0
Installing rubyzip 2.0.0
Fetching msgpack 1.3.1
Installing msgpack 1.3.1 with native extensions
Using bundler 1.17.2
Fetching byebug 11.0.1
Installing byebug 11.0.1 with native extensions
Fetching regexp_parser 1.3.0
Installing regexp_parser 1.3.0
Fetching connection_pool 2.2.2
Installing connection_pool 2.2.2
Fetching safe_yaml 1.0.5
Installing safe_yaml 1.0.5
Fetching dalli 2.7.10
Installing dalli 2.7.10
Fetching declarative 0.0.10
Installing declarative 0.0.10
Fetching declarative-option 0.1.0
Installing declarative-option 0.1.0
Fetching digest-crc 0.4.1
Installing digest-crc 0.4.1
Fetching event_emitter 0.2.6
Installing event_emitter 0.2.6
Fetching ffi 1.11.1
Installing ffi 1.11.1 with native extensions
Fetching raabro 1.1.6
Installing raabro 1.1.6
Fetching jwt 2.2.1
Installing jwt 2.2.1
Fetching memoist 0.16.0
Installing memoist 0.16.0
Fetching os 1.0.1
Installing os 1.0.1
Fetching httpclient 2.8.3
Installing httpclient 2.8.3
Fetching uber 0.1.0
Installing uber 0.1.0
Fetching retriable 3.1.2
Installing retriable 3.1.2
Fetching hashdiff 1.0.0
Installing hashdiff 1.0.0
Fetching hiredis 0.6.3
Installing hiredis 0.6.3 with native extensions
Fetching mini_magick 4.9.5
Installing mini_magick 4.9.5
Fetching jaro_winkler 1.5.3
Installing jaro_winkler 1.5.3 with native extensions
Fetching json 2.2.0
Installing json 2.2.0 with native extensions
Fetching mustache 1.1.0
Installing mustache 1.1.0
Fetching libxml-ruby 3.1.0
Installing libxml-ruby 3.1.0 with native extensions
Fetching rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Installing rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Fetching ruby_dep 1.5.0
Installing ruby_dep 1.5.0
Fetching method_source 0.9.2
Installing method_source 0.9.2
Fetching path_expander 1.1.0
Installing path_expander 1.1.0
Fetching ruby-progressbar 1.10.1
Installing ruby-progressbar 1.10.1
Fetching mono_logger 1.1.0
Installing mono_logger 1.1.0
Fetching mustermann 1.0.3
Installing mustermann 1.0.3
Fetching mysql2 0.5.2
Installing mysql2 0.5.2 with native extensions
Fetching parallel 1.18.0
Installing parallel 1.18.0
Fetching pg 1.1.4
Using psych 3.1.0
Fetching que 0.14.3
Installing pg 1.1.4 with native extensions
Installing que 0.14.3
Fetching racc 1.4.15
Installing racc 1.4.15 with native extensions
Fetching rainbow 3.0.0
Installing rainbow 3.0.0
Fetching rdoc 6.2.0
Installing rdoc 6.2.0
Fetching redcarpet 3.2.3
Installing redcarpet 3.2.3 with native extensions
Fetching redis 4.1.3
Installing redis 4.1.3
Fetching tilt 2.0.10
Installing tilt 2.0.10
Fetching unicode-display_width 1.5.0
Installing unicode-display_width 1.5.0
Fetching sequel 5.25.0
Installing sequel 5.25.0
Fetching sigdump 0.2.4
Installing sigdump 0.2.4
Fetching sprockets-export 1.0.0
Installing sprockets-export 1.0.0
Fetching sqlite3 1.4.1
Installing sqlite3 1.4.1 with native extensions
Fetching stackprof 0.2.13
Installing stackprof 0.2.13 with native extensions
Fetching turbolinks-source 5.2.0
Installing turbolinks-source 5.2.0
Fetching websocket 1.2.8
Installing websocket 1.2.8
Fetching minitest-server 1.0.5
Installing minitest-server 1.0.5
Fetching minitest-retry 0.1.9
Installing minitest-retry 0.1.9
Fetching i18n 1.6.0
Installing i18n 1.6.0
Fetching sucker_punch 2.1.2
Installing sucker_punch 2.1.2
Fetching tzinfo 1.2.5
Installing tzinfo 1.2.5
Fetching nokogiri 1.10.4
Installing nokogiri 1.10.4 with native extensions
Fetching rack-test 1.1.0
Installing rack-test 1.1.0
Fetching sprockets 4.0.0
Installing sprockets 4.0.0
Fetching rack-cache 1.9.0
Installing rack-cache 1.9.0
Fetching rack-protection 2.0.7
Installing rack-protection 2.0.7
Fetching rack-proxy 0.6.5
Installing rack-proxy 0.6.5
Fetching vegas 0.1.11
Installing vegas 0.1.11
Fetching websocket-driver 0.7.1
Installing websocket-driver 0.7.1 with native extensions
Fetching marcel 0.3.3
Installing marcel 0.3.3
Fetching mail 2.7.1
Installing mail 2.7.1
Fetching addressable 2.7.0
Fetching bunny 2.14.3
Installing addressable 2.7.0
Fetching parser 2.6.5.0
Installing bunny 2.14.3
Installing parser 2.6.5.0
Fetching aws-sigv4 1.1.0
Installing aws-sigv4 1.1.0
Fetching faraday 0.17.0
Fetching backburner 1.5.0
Installing faraday 0.17.0
Fetching puma 4.2.1
Installing backburner 1.5.0
Fetching coffee-script 2.4.1
Installing puma 4.2.1 with native extensions
Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
Fetching uglifier 4.2.0
Installing uglifier 4.2.0
Fetching selenium-webdriver 3.142.6
Installing selenium-webdriver 3.142.6
Fetching em-socksify 0.3.2
Installing em-socksify 0.3.2
Fetching thin 1.7.2
Installing thin 1.7.2 with native extensions
Fetching bootsnap 1.4.5
Installing bootsnap 1.4.5 with native extensions
Fetching crack 0.4.3
Installing crack 0.4.3
Fetching representable 3.0.4
Installing representable 3.0.4
Fetching ruby-vips 2.0.15
Fetching rb-inotify 0.10.0
Installing ruby-vips 2.0.15
Installing rb-inotify 0.10.0
Fetching sassc 2.0.1
Fetching minitest-reporters 1.4.0
Installing sassc 2.0.1 with native extensions
Installing minitest-reporters 1.4.0
Using queue_classic 4.0.0.pre.alpha1 from https://github.com/QueueClassic/queue_classic.git (at master@4260d89)
Fetching sdoc 1.0.0
Installing sdoc 1.0.0
Fetching redis-namespace 1.6.0
Installing redis-namespace 1.6.0
Fetching serverengine 2.0.7
Installing serverengine 2.0.7
Fetching turbolinks 5.2.1
Installing turbolinks 5.2.1
Using websocket-client-simple 0.3.0 from https://github.com/matthewd/websocket-client-simple.git (at close-race@e161305)
Fetching minitest-bisect 1.5.1
Using activesupport 6.0.0 from source at `.`
Fetching et-orbi 1.2.2
Installing minitest-bisect 1.5.1
Installing et-orbi 1.2.2
Fetching sinatra 2.0.7
Fetching sidekiq 6.0.1
Installing sidekiq 6.0.1
Installing sinatra 2.0.7
Fetching loofah 2.3.0
Fetching xpath 3.2.0
Installing loofah 2.3.0
Fetching kindlerb 1.2.0
Installing xpath 3.2.0
Fetching w3c_validators 1.3.4
Installing kindlerb 1.2.0
Fetching faye-websocket 0.10.9
Installing w3c_validators 1.3.4
Installing faye-websocket 0.10.9
Fetching aws-sdk-core 3.68.1
Fetching rubocop 0.75.0
Installing aws-sdk-core 3.68.1
Fetching faraday_middleware 0.12.2
Installing faraday_middleware 0.12.2
Fetching signet 0.11.0
Fetching google-cloud-env 1.2.1
Installing signet 0.11.0
Installing google-cloud-env 1.2.1
Fetching blade-sauce_labs_plugin 0.7.3
Fetching qunit-selenium 0.0.4
Installing qunit-selenium 0.0.4
Fetching webdrivers 4.1.3
Installing webdrivers 4.1.3
Fetching em-http-request 1.1.5
Installing em-http-request 1.1.5
Fetching webmock 3.7.6
Installing webmock 3.7.6
Installing blade-sauce_labs_plugin 0.7.3
Fetching listen 3.1.5
Installing listen 3.1.5
Fetching image_processing 1.9.3
Installing image_processing 1.9.3
Fetching sneakers 2.11.0
Installing sneakers 2.11.0
Fetching rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Fetching globalid 0.4.2
Installing globalid 0.4.2
Using activemodel 6.0.0 from source at `.`
Fetching delayed_job 4.1.8
Installing delayed_job 4.1.8
Fetching fugit 1.3.3
Installing fugit 1.3.3
Fetching resque 1.27.4
Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
Installing resque 1.27.4
Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
Fetching capybara 3.29.0
Downloading rubocop-0.75.0 revealed dependencies not in the API or the lockfile
(parser (>= 2.6)).
Either installing with `--full-index` or running `bundle update rubocop` should
fix the problem.
```

Comment: Please read: **"Either installing with `--full-index` or running `bundle update rubocop` should fix the problem."** 

Comment: --full-index  does not fix it, trying bundle update rubocop now but bundle update always causes me headaches

Comment: It's usually fine, but if you get into a jam, give us the specifics and be sure to tell us what you've tried and what happened. Did `--full-index` have any effect at all?

Comment: I'm not alone in the fact that full-index doesn't help at all, see https://makandracards.com/makandra/51932-bundler-error-downloading-gem-revealed-dependencies-not-in-the-api

Comment: full transcript: https://travis-ci.org/oystersauce8/create-rails-app/builds/601931882?utm_medium=notification&utm_source=email

Comment: One thing to try is to delete `Gemfile.lock` and do a `bundle install` to regenerate it. Bundler may be stuck in an inconsistent state.

Comment: now its saying Either installing with `--full-index` or running `bundle update capybara` should

Comment: The --deployment flag requires a Gemfile.lock. Please make sure you have checked
your Gemfile.lock into version control before deploying.

Comment: What I mean is on your dev machine remove the `.lock` file, `bundle install`, and if that install is happy, then put that back in your repo and push it to your CI platform.

Answer (score 4):

Upon @Dennis answer I found the best explanation [here](https://makandracards.com/makandra/51932-bundler-error-downloading-gem-revealed-dependencies-not-in-the-api) by @Dominik Schöler.
See it below:

The error message looks like this:

```
Downloading example-gem-1.2.3 revealed dependencies not in the API or the lockfile (other-gem (< 3)).
Either installing with `--full-index` or running `bundle update example-gem` should fix the problem.
```

However, `bundle install --full-index` did not any better for me, and `bundle update` is not always a viable solution.

Easiest solution:
In `Gemfile.lock` add the dependencies manually by looking for example-gem and adding its dependencies underneath. You may even copy them from the error message.

...

```
GEM
  specs:
    ...
    example-gem (1.2.3)
      other-gem (< 3)
    ...

DEPENDENCIES
```

Now `bundle install` should succeed. If it doesn't, you have probably screwed its syntax. Check your `Gemfile.lock` again.

Comment: You should not touch `Gemfile.lock` manually under any circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

First off, try to remove your Gemfile.lock and run `bundle` again. If that doesn't work, `bundle update <gem name>` might fix the problem. As a last resort, open the Gemfile.lock and add the dependencies manually. Manually look for failing gem and add its dependencies underneath.